# Allocating an object of abstract class type 'CObject'

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

I want to implement CWindow and other elements using polymorphism and abstract class CObject. But I got an error 'Allocating an object of abstract class type 'CObject'.

```
    class CObject
{
public:
    CObject ( const int id, const string &title, const CRect &pos ):
    m_id(id),m_title(title),m_pos(make_unique<CRect>(pos))
    {
    }
    virtual void print ( ostream &os ) const = 0;
    virtual void add ( const CObject &src ){            
        m_src.push_back(make_unique<CObject>(src)); //->here the problem
    }
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const CObject &src ){
        src.print(os);
        return os;
    }
protected:
    int m_id;
    string m_title;
    unique_ptr<CRect> m_pos;
    vector< unique_ptr<CObject> > m_src;
};
```

For example, I want to create a button, and then add the button to the CWindow (in the main function). The window has an absolute position, but other parts of the window depend on the CWindow. Then I want to resize the Window and all of the elements will resize automatically, so I have to store all data about sub-elements.

```
class CWindow : public CObject
    {
    public:
        CWindow ( const string & title, const CRect & absPos ): CObject(0,title,absPos)
        {
        };
        virtual void print ( ostream &os ) const{
            os << "CWindow";
        };
        CWindow & Add ( const CObject &src ){
            add(src);
            return *this;
        }
    };
class CButton : public CObject
{
public:
    CButton ( int  id, const CRect &relPos, const string &name ):
    CObject(id,name,relPos)
    {
    }
};
```

Example of the main function

```
    int main ( void )
    {
         CWindow a ( "Sample window", CRect ( 10, 10, 600, 480 ) );
            a . Add ( CButton ( 1, CRect ( 0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1 ), "Ok" ) ) 
. Add ( CButton ( 2, CRect ( 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1 ), "Cancel" ) );
    }
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

`CObject` is an abstract class, because `print()` is abstract.  As such, you CANNOT create instances of `CObject` directly.  You can only instantiate concrete derived classes that implement `print()`.

Calling `std::make_unique<CObject>(...)` attempts to instantiate `CObject` itself, which is why it fails in your code.  You need to specify a derived class instead, eg: `std::make_unique<CButton>(...)`.

However, the `add()` method you have shown will not work, for a number of reasons:

- there is no way for it to know whether the passed `CObject` was allocated in automatic or dynamic memory.  The `main()` example you have shown is creating objects in automatic memory, but the default deleter of `std::unique_ptr` (`std::delete`) requires dynamic memory instead.
- there is no way for the caller to specify the correct type to pass to the `T` template parameter of `std::make_unique()`.
- none of your derived classes have a constructor that takes a `CObject` as input, so you can't specify the passed `CObject` in the `args` parameter of `std::make_unique()`.

You need to change `add()` to take a `std::unique_ptr<CObject>` as input instead, and then you can just `std::move()` it into your `vector`, eg:

```
virtual void add(std::unique_ptr<CObject> src)
{
    m_src.push_back(std::move(src));
}
```

Let the caller handle constructing the desired object, `add()` just takes ownership of it:

```
int main()
{
    CWindow a("Sample window", CRect(10, 10, 600, 480));
    a.add(std::make_unique<CButton>(1, CRect(0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1), "Ok"));
    a.add(std::make_unique<CButton>(2, CRect(0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1), "Cancel"));
}
```

Otherwise, if you want `add()` to call `std::make_unique()` on the caller's behalf, you would need something more like this instead:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
void add(Args&&... args)
{
    m_src.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(args));
}

...

int main()
{
    CWindow a("Sample window", CRect(10, 10, 600, 480));
    a.add<CButton>(1, CRect(0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1), "Ok");
    a.add<CButton>(2, CRect(0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1), "Cancel");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a method `print` in a class `CObject`. Eg.:

```
virtual void print ( ostream &os ) const {};
```

Comment: So, I can't use CObject like abstract class ?

Comment: Ofc, you can use `CObject` as an abstract class. But you musn't create instance of that class and that is your problem, because `make_unique` constructs an object and wraps it in a std::unique_ptr.